# How to make ListView items height dynamic based on inner content?

Tags: qt, listview, qml, qt-quick, qtquickcontrols2

In following listview's items, length of text can be different (10, or 1000 characters), so I want make each list view item height fit text height.
(Like css height: auto).

```
 Component {
        id: sysNotificationsDelegate        
        Rectangle {
            anchors.left: parent.left
            anchors.right: parent.right
            height: childrenRect.height                        
            color: "#eee"        
            Text {        
                text: model.body // <-- TEXT SIZE CAN BE DIFFERENT     
                wrapMode: Text.WordWrap
            }
        }
    }


ListView {
       anchors.fill: parent            
       spacing: 10

       model: ListModel {
           id: listModel
       }
       delegate: sysNotificationsDelegate    
}
```

What is proper and most performant way to achieve this? (taking into account that I will have a lot of such elements and I've read that property bindings in qml have some additional performance cost)

(Qt 5.10)

Answer (score 7):

For a `Text` to be able to wrap (or elide), it needs to have a width set, otherwise it will expand with no limit.

`Text` has 3 important width properties:

- `width`: consider it the max width of a line of your text, it should always be set unless you don't want to limit the width of your screen (you can scroll or pan horizontally). Setting `wrapMode` or `elide` with no `width` will have no effect.
- `implicitWidth`: the width the text would need to occupy to fit in a single line. Includes the left and right `padding`. Does not depend on the explicit `width`. Not sure when to use it ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ *any ideas in the comments?*
- `contentWidth`: the width the text is actually occupying taking in account the wrapping and eliding. Does not include the left and right `padding`. Depends on the explicit `width`. Use this to query the width of your text, like when you want to draw a box around some text (a chat bubble for example).

The same corresponding properties exist for height too. `maximumLineCount` can limit the height of a text in addition to an explicit `height`

That means that in your case you want to do:

```
Rectangle {
    anchors.left: parent.left
    anchors.right: parent.right
    height: text.contentHeight // contentHeight, height and implicitHeight are all the same here since there's no padding, no maximumLineCount and height isn't explicitely set                        
    color: "#eee"        
    Text {
        id: text
        text: model.body // <-- TEXT SIZE CAN BE DIFFERENT
        width: parent.width // remember, width = max width for Text
        wrapMode: Text.WordWrap
    }
}
```